# Overriding classes and operators in C++

Tags: c++, class, operators, overriding

I am extending this class into an audio book:

```
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;
Book::Book():year(0), title(NULL), authors(NULL){}
Book::Book(vector<string>* bookauthors,string booktitle, int bookyear ){
    authors = bookauthors;
    title = booktitle;
    year = bookyear;
}
Book::Book(const Book& aBook){
    authors = aBook.authors;
    title = aBook.title;
    year = aBook.year;
}
Book::~Book(){
    //delete authors;
    //delete &title;
    //delete &year;
}
bool Book::operator==(const Book &aBook){
    if(getYear() == aBook.getYear() && getTitle() == aBook.getTitle())
        return true;
    else return false;
}
bool Book::operator != (const Book &aBook){
    if(getYear() != aBook.getYear() && getTitle() != aBook.getTitle())
        return true;
    else return false;
}
Book& Book::operator =(const Book& rhs){
    if(this != &rhs){
        authors = rhs.authors;
        title = rhs.title;
        year = rhs.year;
    }
    return *this;
}
void Book::update(int newyear){
    year = newyear;
}
void Book::update(string newtitle){
    title = newtitle;    
}
void Book::update(vector<string>* newauthors){
    authors = newauthors;
}
/*void Book::getAuthors()const{
    for(int i = 0; i < authors->size(); i++){
        cout<<authors->at(i);
    }
}*/
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Book& b){
    os<<b.getTitle()<<", "<<b.getYear();
    for(int i = 0; i < b.authors->size();i++){
        os<<",  "<<b.authors->at(i);
    }
    return os;
}
```

and i keep getting an error for this audiobook class:

```
#include "AudioBook.h"
AudioBook::AudioBook():Book(),length(0){}
AudioBook::AudioBook(vector<string>* authors1, string title1, int year1, double length1){
    Book(authors1, title1, year1);
    length = length1;
}
AudioBook::AudioBook(const AudioBook& other):Book(other),length(other.length){}

AudioBook& AudioBook::operator =(const AudioBook& rhs){
    Book::operator =(rhs);
    length = rhs.length;
}
AudioBook::~AudioBook(){

}
bool AudioBook::operator !=(const AudioBook& aBook){
    Book::operator !=(aBook);
    if(length == aBook.length)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
void AudioBook::update(double newlength){
    length = newlength;
}
/*std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const AudioBook& aBook){
    Book::operator<<(os, aBook);
    os<<"length: "<<aBook.getLength()<<;
}*/
```

this is what i get: libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

i'm not sure if its the override of the operators or what? also how can i override the operator<

Comment: have you tried, using a debugger and looking at the call stack perchance?

Comment: *terminate called after throwing an exception* usually indicates that an exception was thrown and not captured. The fact that it is inside `libc++` is a good hint that it might be a failed `new`. Did you try to allocate too large a size? At any rate run the program in a debugger and have it break on the throwing of the exception. You can then see the state of the program when it was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

`AudioBook& AudioBook::operator =(const AudioBook& rhs)` is missing `return *this;`

Not sure if this is the cause.